# How to use FIFO to communitace between python subprocesss

Tags: python, subprocess, fifo

I try to use Python (2.6) subprocess module to communicated between two external programs. When I started to pump more data 'client' stopped to received everything. I thought it might be related to limited size of subprocess.PIPE object (http://thraxil.org/users/anders/posts/2008/03/13/Subprocess-Hanging-PIPE-is-your-enemy/). So I decided to try fifo, but it didn't worked as expected. How should I use fifo to communicated between two external program called from python script. Currently my script stops at (waiting for another end of fifo):

```
pipe_name = "stream-%s.fifo"%self.transponder
os.mkfifo(pipe_name)
self.stream = Popen(program1, stdout=open(pipe_name,'w'), 
                    stderr=open("test.log",'w'))
```

Comment: Would you be able to post a simple example that we can test and determine what might be incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't manage to get `mkfifo` working. However I managed to have server/client communicate via `os.pipe`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import Popen
import os
from itertools import cycle
from time import sleep
from sys import stdout, executable

def client():
    for letter in cycle('ABCDE'):
        stdout.write(letter)
        stdout.flush()
        sleep(1)


def main(argv=None):
    import sys
    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    argv = argv or sys.argv

    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--client', default=False, action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])

    if args.client:
        client()


    r, w = os.pipe()
    pipe = Popen([executable, __file__, '--client'], stdout=os.fdopen(w, 'w'))

    try:
        client_out = os.fdopen(r, 'r')
        while True:
            letter = client_out.read(1)
            print(letter)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pipe.kill()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You should delete your other answer. Its offsetting your points on this one.